# The length of a rectangle is 6m longer than the width. If the area of a rectangle is $84^2$m, find the dimensions of the rectangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, factoring

I'm in grade 11 math.

The length of a rectangle is $6m$ longer than the width. If the area of a rectangle is $84~\text{m}^2$, find the dimensions of the rectangle. I don't know where to start other than:

$l = w + 6$

$84 = lw$

Comment: Can you solve $84 = (w+6)w$?

Comment: @Zebert This uses the same technique as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627199/the-length-of-a-rectangle-is-4-m-longer-than-its-width-if-the-area-is-8-m) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942451/the-width-of-a-rectangle-is-3-less-than-twice-its-length-if-the-area-of-the-rec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given information, you have the following system of equations to solve:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
L = 6 + W\\
LW = 84\\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Where $W$ denotes the width and $L$ denotes the length.
If we substitute the first relation into the second, it results into the following equation:
\begin{align*}
(6+W)W = 84 \Longleftrightarrow W^{2} + 6W - 84 = 0
\end{align*}

Can you proceed from here?

**EDIT**

Observe that $W^{2} + 6W = (W^{2} + 6W + 9) - 9 = (W+3)^{2} - 9$, from whence we obtain
\begin{align*}
W^{2} + 6W - 84 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (W+3)^{2} - 93 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (W+3)^{2} = 93 \Longleftrightarrow W = \pm\sqrt{93} - 3
\end{align*}

Since $W$ must be positive, we conclude that $W = \sqrt{93}-3$ and $L = \sqrt{93} + 3$.

Another possible approach is to apply the Bhaskara's formula, which is given by:
\begin{align*}
ax^{2} + bx + c = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}
\end{align*}

Comment: I tried but I don't know how. Can you please continue?

Comment: Sure. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $w=l-6$ into $lw=84$ we get
$$
l^2-6l=84\Leftrightarrow l=3\pm \sqrt{93}
$$
Since $l>0$, we get $ l=3+\sqrt{93}$. So $w=\sqrt{93}-3$